# Bulk login attempts on port 22 shutdown our SSH git server access, HTTPs still works though

Tags: ssh, git, sshd, fail2ban

Recently we have been seeing a lot of connections from IPs in to our public `git` server. When this happens, our devs are unable to commit via SSH as the server is very, very slow and I am unable to login via SSH remotely and have to login from the console to resolve the issue. HTTPs to `gitlab` still works when this happens. System resources are plentiful and I have edited `sshd_config` to block all port 22 access unless they have a key. I also have IPS setup to block multiple SSH attempts and have `fail2ban` on the server.

With all that setup, I am unsure how this is creating such an issue for the server. I can resolve the issues by restarting the `sshd` service and blocking the offending subnets, but why is it messing up SSH so much that it makes the server unusable via SSH? Are all of these attempts somehow using all of the ports and therefore blocking legit access attempts? Below is a copy of the `secure` log file with an attempt. Note, there is a big time gap from 14:30:18 to 14:30:50.

```
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5924]: Connection from 11.11.11.11 port 62290
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5924]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version libssh-0.11
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5924]: debug1: no match: libssh-0.11
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5924]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5924]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
Sep  4 14:30:17 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
Sep  4 14:30:18 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Sep  4 14:30:18 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
Sep  4 14:30:18 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Sep  4 14:30:18 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: KEX done
Sep  4 14:30:18 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive
Sep  4 14:30:50 somegitserver sshd[5944]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Sep  4 14:30:51 somegitserver sshd[5941]: debug1: do_cleanup
Sep  4 14:30:51 somegitserver sshd[5945]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 10 sock 11
Sep  4 14:30:51 somegitserver sshd[5944]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Sep  4 14:30:51 somegitserver sshd[5924]: debug1: do_cleanup
Sep  4 14:30:51 somegitserver sshd[5945]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Sep  4 14:30:51 somegitserver sshd[5961]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
Sep  4 14:30:51 somegitserver sshd[5924]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is fail2ban actually blocking failed connections?  are you seeing lots of entries like `NOTICE  [sshd] Unban ip.ip.ip.ip` in your `/var/log/fail2ban.log` (or wherever it is on your system)?   also, if you are running gitlab in a container (e.g. the `gitlab/gitlab-ce` docker image), fail2ban on the host won't see the container's auth logs unless you configure it to watch them as well as the system's own auth logs.

Comment: btw, have you considered running a private git server for devs to upload to, and a public git server for others to clone from?

Comment: I am not seeing any entries in `fail2ban.log` file. Will `fail2ban` not work since `sshd_config` is blocking all connections unless it uses a key?

Comment: no, that is an auth failure and is something that would be logged by sshd.  are you seeing that in your `/var/log/auth.log` (or wherever auth failures are logged on your system)?   is f2b configured to monitor that log file and block ssh failures? i.e. do you have `enabled=true` under the `[sshd]` section of your f2b jail.conf (or jail.local)?

Comment: I did not have `fail2ban` setup properly. It is now blocking SSH attempts from the correct log file

Comment: i though it would be something like that.  if you write that up as an answer, you can accept it and this question can be marked as solved. i'll probably upvote it too.   BTW, in case you're wondering: it's completely OK to accept your own answer to your own question.

Comment: Okay cool -- I will update with the correct answer when I finish. I want to make sure I have a solid answer to my specific question. The blocking is working from `f2b`, but it is not exactly what I wanted... yet. I had to update to the newer version of `f2b` to get the correct blocking. Thank you.

Comment: ping me (by putting `@cas` in a comment) when you've posted your answer so I'll see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with my `fail2ban` config not reading the correct log file. Once I updated my `jail.local` file and specified `/var/log/secure` instead of `/var/log/sshd.log`, I was starting to see IPs go in to the jail. This had `fail2ban` working but it still wasn't blocking certain log entries. I wanted to block specific entries that contained `11: Bye Bye` but my custom filter in `fail2ban` was not working: `^%(__prefix_line)sReceived disconnect from <HOST>: 11: \S+: *$`

To completely resolve my issue, I found that version `0.10.5.dev1` of `fail2ban` could catch that specific entry in the log file by default. I upgraded and redid the config and it is now working as I hoped.

Comment: thanks to `@cas` for guidance on this

Comment: good answer.   BTW, you probably could have just copied the rule from the updated version into your filter.d/ssh file.  or the entire file.  Something to keep in mind in future, because upgrading to the latest dev version isn't always a good idea.

Comment: I thought about doing this but the way the new version deals with the blocking is a little different. But you are right, I was hesitant to update to a dev version.